# What is the best way to implement a deposit system with Monero's RPC calls?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc, php, stagenet

I'm currently building up a service where the user can deposit multiple cryptos. One of them is Monero, and that is where I'm stuck at the moment.

I use PHP for this and the following project: https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp

I tried to play around and thought the best way would be the following:
- generate an address
- check for incoming transfers of the given address

The problem is, that I can generate the address but anyway, when I'm using incoming_transfers or get_transfers, neither I get the needed transactions. I get all of the transactions belonging to the wallet.

Maybe I misunderstood the concept (accounts, addresses, subadresses) as Monero is rather new to me. Can somebody give me a hint what would be the best way to archive the result I want?

I don't need any code, just point me into the right direction, so I can have a look at it! :)

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I am new to crypto and i am also trying to use same above project but don't know how to use it
Do I need to install monero wallet first in my pc/hosting? To user monero wallet commands?
I am trying to build monero exchange I have knowledge of php and already developed many websites in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a subaddress per customer. Therefore, you will be calling the RPC method [create_address](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_address) (if using the `monero-wallet-rpc` directly), or the [equivalent method](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp/blob/master/docs/walletRPC.md#create_address) in your referenced PHP wrapper library.

To check for incoming payments, you can use [incoming_transfers](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#incoming_transfers) (or the [equivalent](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp/blob/master/docs/walletRPC.md#incoming_transfers) library method). Depending on your use case, you can request all subaddress incoming payments (e.g. don't supply the optional `subaddr_indices` parameter), or specific subbaddresses by specififying their respective indices in the `subaddr_indices` array parameter. An even better approach is to make use of the `monero-wallet-rpc` parameter `--tx-notify` which will execute a program each time you receive a payment, thus preventing the need for polling.

```
monero-wallet-rpc --help
...
  --tx-notify arg                   Run a program for each new incoming 
                                    transaction, '%s' will be replaced by 
                                    the transaction hash
```

You can then check which subaddress was deposited to by using [get_transfer_by_txid](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_transfer_by_txid).

A good overview of accounts and subaddresses can be found at https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that is likely the way I was doing it already but incoming_transfers gives me back all transactions of the account.

Creating the sub address is fine and works very well. I tried using incoming_transfers with the address itself as subaddress_indices or using an integer. This really bugs me, I cant see any fault. :/

Comment: `subaddr_indices` is an array of integers, not the actual address(es).

Comment: THANKS! That was the problem, I just tried using the index as integer, wrapping it up in an array brought the correct result! :-)